# Kivy widgets underneath other widgets are interactable, how to prevent this?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Consider an app containing a button in a `RelativeLayout`. If any widget, aside from a button, is placed atop of it, thus hiding the button, this button and any other children to the `RelativeLayout`  will be interactable even if it not visible.

What can be done to force this functionality?

Here is an example: notice how the button in the center of the app still receives touch events, despite being completely hidden:

````
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        
        def btn_pressed(instance):
            print('ok')
        
        root = RelativeLayout()
        button = Button()
        root.add_widget(button)
        
        button.size_hint = (None, None)
        button.pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        button.bind(on_press=btn_pressed)
        
        layout = RelativeLayout()
        with layout.canvas:
            Color(0,0,0,1)
            Rectangle(size=(Window.size[0], Window.size[1]))
        
        root.add_widget(layout)
        
        return root

MyApp().run() ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for most widgets is to allow touch events to continue to be dispatched. This is controlled by the return value of the `on_touch_XXX()` methods. A `True` return means "do not continue dispatching" and a `False` return means "continue dispatching". So you can halt the dispatch of `on_touch_down` events by defining a custom class that stops the dispatching. For example:

```
class MyTouchBlocker(RelativeLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return True
        else:
            return super(MyTouchBlocker, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

And in your code, you can replace:

```
layout = RelativeLayout()
```

with:

```
layout = MyTouchBlocker()
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.dispatch).